# What should be the equivalent logrotate script for CentOS 8

Tags: ubuntu, centos, apache-httpd, logrotate

I have a logrotate script for some of my log files at our Ubuntu server. The script is give below.

```
/home/*/logs/*log {
        su root root
        notifempty
        daily
        rotate 7
        compress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if [ -f "`. /etc/apache2/envvars ; echo ${APACHE_PID_FILE:-/var/run/apache2.pid}`" ]; then
                        /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
                fi
        endscript
}
```

Now I want to implement the same script in my CentOS 8 server. Here I can't understand what will be the value for the lines

```
if [ -f "`. /etc/apache2/envvars ; echo ${APACHE_PID_FILE:-/var/run/apache2.pid}`" ]; then
        /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use what the base CentOS `httpd` package uses in its [httpd.logrotate](https://git.centos.org/rpms/httpd/blob/c8s-stream-2.4/f/SOURCES/httpd.logrotate):

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    delaycompress
    postrotate
        /bin/systemctl reload httpd.service > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

(Also, I suggest you not use /home as a place to store web sites.  I imagine pretty much everything breaks unless you turn off SELinux?  That’s why.  In addition to that, your recipe will compress logs for every user who happens to have a homedir with a log directory.  I suppose if you have only users that are websites… )